# Squeeze Force for Anodizing Apparatus

Tags: springs

I have an anodizing rack that has hundreds of prongs. These prongs are made of titanium and need to be squeezed together in order to place the parts on the rack. I am wondering how I would calculate the force needed to make the prongs touch so that parts can be added?

I have seen some people saying to use F=kx treating the prongs as a spring, would this be the best way? Any help is appreciated.

[image: titanium prongs]

Comment: Just use a split cone in front of the piece that guides the prongs into the part, then separate the cone and remove...

Comment: if you have the device in hand measure it don't try to calculate it.